# React-vis y axis scale

Tags: d3.js, react-vis

I have a bar chart in a react-vis component.  I allow react-vis to calculate the y axis but it never seems to go to the end of the full range of y values.

For example...

This is what I get by default..,

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this...

[image]

I can get what I want by changing a single line in node_modules/d3-array/src/ticks.js.

If I change this line...

```
while (++i < n) ticks[i] = (start + i) * step;
```

to

```
while (++i <= n) ticks[i] = (start + i) * step;
```

then, 1 extra tick value is generated and using CSS I can make it visible which satisfies my requirement.  I don't want to go editing the source here.

Does anyone know of another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

For the parent XYPlot componet, you can control the range of what's shown using yDomain.

For your example, try something like:
yDomain={[0, maxValue * 1.25]}